OpenXR "Failed to create GL context!"
So I bought a used VR headset (Samsung Odyssey+) and wanted to try to get it to work with my Linux machine.  Encountering some dependency problems, over the past two days I broke and twice reinstalled Ubuntu, and just got everything working again as well as upgraded to Ubuntu 24.04.  Following internet posts, I built Envision to build Monado, and started it up.  And got:
Error   [/home/erhannis/.local/share/envision/monado/src/xrt/auxiliary/util/u_debug_gui.c:sdl2_window_init]
    Failed to create GL context!
Monado exited with code 11

Googling gives few results - but one of them is that "Intel HD4000 doesn't support OpenGL 4.1".  This would be a plausible cause, assuming 4.1 is required, except that glxinfo says Device: Mesa Intel(R) HD Graphics 4000 (IVB GT2) (0x166)...Max core profile version: 4.2.  So what's up, then?  Is there another reason it might "fail to create GL context"?  A way to work around it?  Or did I just waste 12 hours breaking and fixing my computer, for a device it fundamentally can't support?
Update: I don't have the headset working quite yet, but I don't think the problem is as fundamental as I initially suspected.  It looks like if I just change Monado's u_debug_gui.c:sdl2_window_init SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 5); from 5 to 2, it no longer has an obvious problem - the debug gui starts up fine and renders a user interface.  More than that, I have (inconsistently) gotten tracking data off the headset!  Unfortunately, I've never gotten the headset to display anything.  Ubuntu doesn't acknowledge the display's existence - save for one hazy moment where I THINK xrandr said HDMI1 was connected.  Not totally sure I'm not mixing that up with when I connected a real monitor.  When I toggle the HMD on/off from Monado, my task bar blips in briefly, which makes me suspect SOMETHING is happening, but I don't know what.
